# How to highlight the current chapter while playing the video on the chapter menu of the youtube chapter marker player

Tags: javascript, css, youtube, youtube-api, google-api

I'm new to programming. I just want to know, how do I highlight the current chapter while playing the video on the chapter menu of the youtube chapter marker player.

Live link :  http://gdata-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ytplayer/ChapterMarkerPlayer/index.html

Full CSS : http://gdata-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ytplayer/ChapterMarkerPlayer/chapter_marker_player.css

Full javascript : http://gdata-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ytplayer/ChapterMarkerPlayer/chapter_marker_player.js

Can anyone please provide me some codes or samples similar to this. So, I can get some idea how to do this.. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

The youtube api has this script

```
function getCurrentTime() {
   ytplayer.getCurrentTime();
}
```

Where "ytplayer" is your targeted player.

I would say then you can use

```
setInterval(getCurrentTime(), 3000);
```

and check if it matches.

You would need to have **var's** set up with values to test against.

= to ? but < ??

After that the script can change the css of the div accordingly. onClick would need to have the same result.

Answer (score -1):

New Codes:

```
function clearList() {

  var list  = document.getElementById("chapter-list"); 
  var items = list.getElementsByTagName("li"); 

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 

      items[i].removeAttribute("class"); 

  }

}

function highlightChapter(player) {

  setInterval(function() { 

    var status = player.getPlayerState();

    if (status>0) {

        var currentTime = player.getCurrentTime() ;

        list = document.getElementById('chapter-list');

        for (var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {

          var time = times[i];
          var item = list.children[i];

          if (currentTime>=time) {

            clearList();
            item.setAttribute('class', 'current');

          }

        }
    }  

  }, 1000);      

}
```

Edited Code:

```
function addChapterMarkers(containerElement, player) {
  var ol = document.createElement('ol');
  ol.setAttribute('class', 'chapter-list');
  ol.setAttribute('id', 'chapter-list'); ////////////// HERE
  ol.setAttribute('style', 'width: ' + width + 'px');
  containerElement.appendChild(ol);

  for (var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
    var time = times[i];
    var chapterTitle = params.chapters[time];

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.setAttribute('data-time', time);
    li.textContent = formatTimestamp(time) + ': ' + chapterTitle;

    li.onclick = function() {
      // 'this' will refer to the element that was clicked.
      player.seekTo(this.getAttribute('data-time'));

      //my code
      clearList(); //// ADDITIONAL CODE
      this.setAttribute('class', 'current');  //// ADDITIONAL CODE
      // end my code

    };
    ol.appendChild(li);
  }
}

function insertPlayerAndAddChapterMarkers(params) {
  var containerElement = document.getElementById(params.container);
  if (!containerElement) {
    throw 'The "container" parameter must be set to the id of a existing HTML element.';
  }
  var player = initializePlayer(containerElement, params);
  addChapterMarkers(containerElement, player);

  highlightChapter(player); ////// INSERT


}
```

Comment: It's helpful to give the OP an answer as to what they were doing incorrectly instead of just code blocks!